# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered

Tags: spring, rest, jpa

I am using CRUDRepository to perform crud operations using JPA , but I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered

Please help.

Comment: looks like you use incompatible versions. Please post the relevant part of your pom.xml or list the relevant libs (jars). Also please post the complete stacktrace, because it would show which libary trys to invoke the "not existing" method.

Comment: please find below entire stack trace

Comment: i am using spring-data-jpa-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Thats not the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes from this commit:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/6677612f8eac7a7ab67206a5709b6e94cc51028b

So you'll need at least spring-data-commons 1.10.0.RELEASE:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But: if this is happening is probably because you've a conflict between versions, so it's better if you find out why you are loading an older spring-data-commons

Comment: In my project we were using solr so spring-data-solr was taking old version of spring-data-common. This answer should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this error , earlier i was using spring-data-jpa.1.7.2.RELEASE.jar , now i switched on to spring-data-jpa.1.6.0.RELEASE.jar and it solved the problem

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Often this happens when you have 2 dependencies in your maven pom.xml file with the same "groupId" but different versions.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Common "groupId"'s should have the same version number.